# How to import maven into my Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, maven

There is a library that I would like to use for my Android App: [ez Vcard](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard). However this library uses Maven, which I'm not familiar with. I checked online and my Import Project objection doesn't offer pom.xml soo, how can I add the dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.ez-vcard</groupId>
   <artifactId>ez-vcard</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

into my project and specifically where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a maven project, you can use maven dependencies in gradle projects, you'll just have to use a gradle format of the dependency.

This library appears to be hosted on maven central, so you have to link to this repository host in your global **build.gradle**:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

To import this dependency into your project, in your module-local **build.gradle** file input the following lines:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.9.9'
    // all the other dependencies...
}
```

You can actually see [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.googlecode.ez-vcard%7Cez-vcard%7C0.9.9%7C) all the different dependency formats (under 'Dependency Information'), from maven to gradle, ivy, sbt and so on, they are all compatible with the repository.

Comment: Ohh I got it! Managed to compile it in my gradle. Thank you so much, really 'ppreciate your help! Good day :-)